# What's the Save As keyboard shortcut?

Tags: microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, microsoft-word-2010

In MS Word 2010, I have certain documents I want to Save As so I don't have to keep making duplicates. It's quite annoying to go to the File tab and click 'Save As', so I want to try and use the keyboard shortcut.

The most common shortcut is <kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>S</kbd>. I tried it, but here's the result: [Word](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eb8wR.png)

What's the keyboard shortcut for 'Save As' in MS Word 2010?

Comment: I've googled "word 2010 save as shortcut" and the first link contained the answer. It was faster than typing out a question like yours and I got the answer instantly!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve this with <kbd>F12</kbd>.